# Merging Case fields into Visualforce email template?

Tags: email-template, visualforce-template

I'm using the Messaging.SingleEmailMessage class to send an email (using a VF template), merging in some Case fields.

Where do you specify what record should be used for the merge fields in the template? **In other words, how do I tell Apex what Case/Case ID to send to the template?**

`setTargetObjectId` seems like it might be the method to use, and it's required if you're using a VF template - but it sounds like this has to be a Contact, Lead, or User - I also tried setting this to a flat Case ID and while there were no compile or runtime errors, the template didn't "receive" the Case ID.

**Execute anonymous:**

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
email.setToAddresses(new String[] { 'test@test.com' });
email.setTargetObjectId('00563000000WyiwAAC'); // attempting to use a Case ID here does not result in a compilation or runtime error
email.setTemplateId('00X63000000M2rbEAC');
email.saveAsActivity = false;
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { email });
```

**Template:**

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Template 1"  relatedToType="Case">
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >

Visualforce Email Template.
<c:ConsumerCommunicationTemplate caseIdAttribute="{!relatedTo.Id}"/>

</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

In the template, if I change the component markup to a flat Case ID like so:

```
<c:ConsumerCommunicationTemplate caseIdAttribute="00563000000WyiwAAC"/>
```

it works fine. This is the only reason I'm not sure it's an issue with the component and the order of instantiation of its constructor/getters/setters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friend here is the `setWhatId(someCaseId)` method as documented here in the [Apex doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm?search_text=setWhatId)

This corresponds to the `{!relatedTo.Id}` merge field in the VF email template that you can pass into your custom VF component

```
<c:ConsumerCommunicationTemplate caseIdAttribute="{!relatedTo.Id}"/>
```